# Prevent endnotes/footnotes from duplicating on beamer when using animations

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, footnotes, endnotes

I am making a Beamer presentation and I use pauses between contents of  the slides.  I've managed to make it so that the in-text endnote numbers and the appendix endnote numbers are clickable and allow me to jump back and forth. But I can't figure out how to display the endnotes without them being duplicated when outside of handout mode. (Each one gets duplicated as many times as there are frames generated by the pauses.) I'm using `enotez` but believe this is a wider issue.

Here's the example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\mode<presentation>
\useoutertheme[subsection=false, footline=authortitle]{miniframes}
\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{backref = true} %allows it to link back to text from clicking on the endnote
 \DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{custom}{paragraph}
{
notes-sep = 1.4\baselineskip 
}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}

\begin{document}

\section{Temporal monotonicity}
\begin{frame}{Title}
In Lecture X...
\begin{itemize}
    \item funders of a public good have different discount rates and
    \item a patient funder ...\endnote{Example endnote 1.}
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.4cm}
\pause
The model we used to explore these dynamics assumed...\endnote{Example endnote 2.}\\
\vspace{0.4cm}
\pause
More text.\endnote{Example endnote 3.}\\
\vspace{0.4cm}
\pause
We first explored a ``spend at $t$ $\to$ benefit at $t$'' model...\endnote{Example endnote 4.}
\end{frame}

\appendix
\begin{frame}[t, allowframebreaks]{}
\def\newblock{}
    \printendnotes[custom]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: example compiled]

Things I've tried

- Experimenting with other ways of specifying overlays like adding `<3->` after `\endnote`
- Looked into similar problems with footnotes on beamer and explored those solutions (e.g. [Footnote rule in beamer showing too early with overlays](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70666/footnote-rule-in-beamer-showing-too-early-with-overlays) or [Beamer: Footnote appears twice when used in a frame title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376079/beamer-footnote-appears-twice-when-used-in-a-frame-title) or [Footnotes duplicated with overlays and `show notes on second screen`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644578/footnotes-duplicated-with-overlays-and-show-notes-on-second-screen) )
- Trying to contact enotez package maintainers (no response so far)
- I also tried things like `\only<4->` before `\endnote{}`. This does remove duplicated instances but then shows the endnote content in-text for all the frames before the 4th and only actually shows an endnote in that specified (4th) frame.

The ideal solution would be global, without me having to specify overlays for each endnote